# Showing a message to the user in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My problem is not the coding but a general design question. I wrote a chrome extension that connects a user through a socks5 proxy (via ssh) to a vpn network. If the proxy process is killed or the connection is interupted the socks proxy will reconnect and on successful connection the (failed) tabs are reloaded. While connecting to the network the browseraction icon is slightly animated. This works fine so far.

What I want now is a decent but visible hint, that there is something going on in the background and that the user has to wait a few seconds until he clicks a link or opens a tab. I already thought about alerts, but anybody hates them and of course they are right. Then I thought about an animated message like twitter or growl, but injecting a page with a content script does not seem to work on error pages. Also showing messages at the browseraction as text or showing a popup doesn't seem to be possible.

My question is: Does anybody of you know an extension where this is solved nicely or have an idea how to solve this. It should be visible at first sight without being anoying. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can animate the browser action or page action icon. See an example: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#9a6e4ec46997fb92b324974afa08a3d007e2537f

Comment: Yes I already done this, but it is very descent. Red and yellow blinking Icons suck somehow. :-)

Comment: it's an issue of design. I animated 16 icons, and it looked like this:  http://ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif

Comment: My icon keeps the original icon (a glossy world) at a lower opacity and before that a dark blue spinner rotates. Of course this is visible, but if you have many extension installed or you are reading on a page you might not see it. If I could I would show just a little layer in the right upper corner with a sentence, that there is a reconnect but as I said this does not seem to work properly.

Comment: And thinking about this, there might be more problems. What if the connection is permanently interupted? Or the traffic limit is reached? In a text box, I could tell this to the user but not with an icon. I know these are "luxury problems" but I just want to make it as perfect as possible. :-/